# Does Google Cloud Storage Object Change Notification support lifecycle events?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Can/do lifecycle events on cloud storage objects like deletes trigger object change notifications?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will get an object notification when a lifecycle action is performed.